# Create closed form approximation of non-closed form integral

Tags: integration

Let there be a function $f(x_0)$ that does not have a closed-form integral.

The function $g(x_0)$ is defined as $\int_{-\infty}^{x_0} f(x)dx$

Numeric integration allows the approximate to area under the curve for a particular $x_0$, but how can we make a closed form approximation of the function $g(x_0)$?

In other words, I want a closed form function to approximate $g(x_0)$ so I do not have to perform numeric integration for every different $x_0$.

How might this be done? Markov chain Monte Carlo?

Comment: Monte Carlo is not closed form. None will be possible in general. For a particular $f$ you might be lucky.

Comment: Even if you're doing things numerically, you can take advantage of the fact that $g(x_0^\prime)=g(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x_0^\prime}f(x)dx$ if you want to do less work for different points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you need these improper integrals to converge.  Here's one way to do it.  Let's say you want $g(x_0)$ for $x_0$ in an interval: for convenience I'll take this to be $[0,1]$, but 
it's easy to adapt this to other intervals.  First approximate $\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)\; dx$ as $J_0$ (using some numerical method).  For $0 \le x \le 1$ take a Fourier series approximation
$$\eqalign{f(x) &\approx\frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N (a_n \cos(2 n \pi x) + b_n \sin(2 n \pi x))\cr
a_n &= 2 \int_0^1 f(x) \cos(2n\pi x)\; dx\cr
b_n &= 2 \int_0^1 f(x) \sin(2n\pi x)\; dx\cr}$$
(again, evaluating these coefficients using some numerical method). Then
$$ g(x_0) \approx J_0 + \frac{a_0 x_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{a_n \sin(2n\pi x_0) + b_n (1-\cos(2n\pi x_0))}{2\pi n} $$